# How to create this JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

Sorry for the bad title, but I don't know how to create following JSON in PHP:

```
{ 
   "id":"1",
   "method":"getData",
   "params":{ 
      "options":{ 
         "element":{ 
            "id":"1a_ext",
            "type":1,
            "keyType":"externalkey"
         },
         "moreInfo":true,
         "userFields":[ 
            "id",
            "name",
            "longname",
            "externalkey"
         ]
      }
   },
   "jsonrpc":"2.0"
}
```

I don't know to do the part after "params" (how do I "put" options "into" params) - for the other parts I know what I have to do:

```
public static function getData(){
            $json = array(
                "id" => self::id(),
                "method" => "getData",
                "params" => array(
                    "id" => self::$userid,
                    "type" => self::$type
                ),
                "jsonrpc" => "2.0"
            );
            $json = json_encode($json, true);
            return self::request($json);
        }
```

I would really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: You can check result of json_decode($jsonString, true), for example. This will return array as you need and using this info you will create needed method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the this in array format in PHP and then JSON encode:

```
$arr = [
    'id' => 1,
    'method' => 'getData',
    'params' => [
        'options' => [
            'element' => [
                'id' => '1a_ext',
                'type' => 1,
                'keyType' => 'externalKey'
            ],
            'moreInfo' => true,
            'userFields' => [
                'id',
                'name',
                'longname',
                'externalKey'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'jsonrpc' => '2.0'
];

$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You directly can assign to the `params` keys like

```
$json['params']['options'] = $your_options;
```

Full version of your code as an example

```
public static function getData(){
    $json = array(
        "id" => self::id(),
        "method" => "getData",
        "params" => array(
            "id" => self::$userid,
            "type" => self::$type
        ),
        "jsonrpc" => "2.0"
    );

    # add something to param index
    $json['params']['options'] = $your_options;

    $json = json_encode($json, true);
    return self::request($json);
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `true` as a second param for `json_encode`?

Comment: for bitmasking during encoding, we have to pass true as an option.

Comment: The second param excepts an int (a flag) not a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spoonfeeding, i would like to help related, Whenever if you find difficulties to create an array representation of a JSON then you should use `var_export(array, true)` the second parameter must be **true** to return the variable representation instead of outputting it

```
<?php
    $json_str = '{
      "id": "1",
      "method": "getData",
      "params": {
        "options": {
          "element": {"id": "1a_ext", "type": 1, "keyType": "externalkey"},
          "moreInfo": true,
          "userFields": ["id", "name", "longname", "externalkey"]
        }
      },
      "jsonrpc": "2.0"
    }';
    $json_arr = var_export(json_decode($json_str, true), true);
    print_r($json_arr);
```

check the output here https://paiza.io/projects/eUZZDsTsSFSM4m9WMl05Ow

`$json_arr` is an array representation for your JSON, now you can dynamic the array values