# How do I parse this array in PHP?

Tags: php, json

Yesterday I asked this question: [How to create this JSON in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026339/how-to-create-this-json-in-php)

This works perfectly and now I have to parse the reply from the server - he gives my an array like this example below. How can I run through this and get things like startTime and the following name?

And why does

```
<?php $json = file_get_contents("URL");
$data = json_decode($json);
$time1 = $data[0][1]['startTime'];
?>
```

not work? Please help me to understand this and please explain me how I can get to an solution next time when I have an array or JSON to parse and what you do when you have to parse things like this.

And is there any tool available, where you post the code and can click on the requested item and it shows you the code how to get this?

Array from server:

```
Array (
    [jsonrpc] => 2.0
    [id] => 6d41c7a9e35e441c4e9b66e267523927
    [result] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [id] => 403230
            [date] => 20190923
            [startTime] => 1240
            [endTime] => 1330
            [kl] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => Radiodata
                    )
                )
            [te] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => MUS
                    [longname] => Music
                    )
                )
            [su] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => MUS
                    [longname] => Music
                    )
                )
            [ro] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 31
                    )
                )
            [activityType] => Music-Only
            )
        [1] => Array (
            [id] => 403231
            [date] => 20190923
            [startTime] => 1335
            [endTime] => 1425
            [kl] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => Radiodata
                    )
                )
            [te] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => MUS
                    [longname] => Music
                    )
                )
            [su] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => MUS
                    [longname] => Music
                    )
                )
            [ro] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 31
                    )
                )
            [activityType] => Music-Only
            )
        [2] => Array (
            [id] => 407790
            [date] => 20190923
            [startTime] => 1520
            [endTime] => 1610
            [kl] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => Radiodata
                    )
                )
            [te] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => MUS
                    [longname] => Music
                    )
                )
            [su] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => MUS
                    [longname] => Music
                    )
                )
            [ro] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 24
                    )
                )
            [activityType] => Music-Only
            )
        [3] => Array (
            [id] => 407791
            [date] => 20190923
            [startTime] => 1610
            [endTime] => 1700
            [kl] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => Radiodata
                    )
                )
            [te] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => MUS
                    [longname] => Music
                    )
                )
            [su] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] => MUS
                    [longname] => Music
                    )
                )
            [ro] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 24
                    )
                )
            [activityType] => Radiodata
            )
        )
```

Comment: Can you format the array so we can see the nesting? Or just post the JSON after formatting it at jsonlint.com.

Comment: You want `$data['result'][0]['startTime']`, don't you?

Comment: @arkascha correct, but I do not get an output with this.

Comment: Then what you posted above is _not_ the exact data you have.

Comment: But this is exactly the data ...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you parse the json with wrong key. Check this code which will help you

```
    <?php 
    $json = file_get_contents("URL");
    $data = json_decode($json,true);

    foreach($data['result'] as $resData)
    {
        $startTime=$resData['startTime'];
        $endtime=$resData['endTime'];
        echo($startTime); 
        foreach($resData['kl'] as $klData)
        {
            $klname=$klData['name'];
            echo($klname);
            echo '<br>';

        }
        foreach($resData['te'] as $teData)
        {
        $tename=$teData['name'];
        $echo($tename);
        echo '<br>';

        }
    }

    ?>
```

Output:

```
Radiodata
MUS
Radiodata
MUS
Radiodata
MUS
Radiodata
MUS
```

Comment: yaa but you can also use the for loop but i like foreach in that case. Hope this code run perfectly. if you stick with this  json_decode($json); then you need $data->result in foreach loop and if you use json_decode($json,true) then you can simply use $data['result'] (which i like most)

Comment: I tried your code now, but I do not get any output ... there's something wrong ...

Comment: can you share the url if you don't have any problem. I think this code is correct but output json may be differ because if output json is in correct format that you pasted then this code run perfectly

Comment: I pasted it again here: https://pastebin.com/VLC61m42
This is the exact code I get when I view it in my browser (without any parsing oder json_decode!)

Comment: Tried again - I checked the logs and get "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 5"

Comment: which means you entered the wrong url or API url not giving the data. can you use the   $json = file_get_contents("URL");
              $data = json_decode($json);
              echo('<pre>');
              echo(json_encode($data));
              echo('<pre>');

AND SEND THE OUTPUT WHAT IT GIVES

Comment: It does definitely work - checked it in restlet client too: https://picr.eu/i/f2qJF

This does give "null".

Comment: If I use print_r($json); after file_get_contents it shows me all data.

Comment: if this is your api then remove the line(echo $array) which gives this output html content type. Just add the (echo json_encode($array)) this will give the json because your API return the content type is html that cannot be parsable so you should do the contect type application/json in your API.